# Visual Studio 2012 Command Prompt expected environment pathway not included

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, command-prompt

Recently installed (and re-installed) VS 2012 Ultimate with Blend

The `VS Command Prompt` doesn't seem to have a reference (are they called environment pathways) to the folder "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\". This means the following lines won't run from the command prompt (either as normal or as administrator)

- `msbuild buildapp.csproj /t:HelloWorld`
- `Installutil WindowsService1.exe`

To use msbuild or Installutil I need to specify the full pathways for the above to run.

Is the above a by design change that MS have made to VS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my VS 2012 environment I can find the path you say is missing. I opened the "Developer Command Prompt for VS2012" and did PATH to verify and also ran InstallUtil.exe successfully.

Make sure you open the correct prompt, mine was started using `%comspec% /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"`

Comment: oh well - must be something wrong with my install. This in itself isn't such a big deal as I just need to remember to put in the complete pathway. Would be nice to safely fix it just not too sure where I need to add that pathway. Slightly worried there might be other problems with the install.

Comment: I have never looked into these files before, but this is what I found. VsDevCmd.bat has lots of logic where it builds the Path based on several factors, key is called VCVarsQueryRegistry.bat which read .NET and VS settings from the Registry. If you go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools, what do you see? you should at least have guidgen.exe I supposed. I have three BAT-files at the end which seems to be used when opening the VS Dev CMD

Comment: do you have multiple instances of `installutil` on your machine - I have so maybe the VS install deliberately left this environ path out to foce me to choose which version of `installutil` I use?

Comment: I have versions of InstallUtil for .NET 2.0 and .NET 4.0, and for each there are 32- and 64-bit versions. I find such advanced logic when setting Path to be improbable.

Comment: I've run it now - and used it to install the Windows Service. So I will just have to remember to put in the full pathway to those exe's when using command prompt. Not the end of the world

Answer (score 2):

Here's Microsoft's explanation (err..justification :)) of the convoluted path structure :

For 32 bit builds :

[Setting the Path and Environment Variables for Command-Line Builds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt.aspx)

.. and 64 bit builds :

[How to: Enable a 64-Bit Visual C++ Toolset on the Command Line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4d2c09s.aspx)